# Backslashes remains after JSON.parse()

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

**Updated:**

Data coming from server is:

```
var data = {
         "files":[
                      {
                         "filename": "29f96b40-cca8-11e2-9f83-1561fd356a40.png",
                         "cdnUri":"https://abc.s3.amazonaws.com/"
                      }
                   ]
                }
```

I keep JSON data in a hidden input field:

**Updated:**

```
$('#logoVal').val(JSON.stringify(file));
```

And the HTML is:

```
<input id="logoVal" type="hidden" value="{"filename":"29f96b40-cca8-11e2-9f83-1561fd356a40.png","cdnUri":"https://abc.s3.amazonaws.com/"}" name="logo">
```

When I submit the form, I do that:

```
var data = $("#form").serializeArray();
data.logo = JSON.parse($('#logoVal').val());
```

But the logo becomes:

```
"logo": "{\"filename\":\"72553050-cca2-11e2-9c13-7d08f99324cc.png\",\"cdnUri\":\"https://abc.s3.amazonaws.com/\"}",
```

in the mongo database.

What can I do?

Comment: You apparently need to decode it again. Unless you mean there shouldn't be backslashes, but without those you get an invalid string.

Comment: That HTML is invalid, you will need to escape the quotes - they're attribute value delimiters. And why do you have apostrophes around your JSON?

Comment: Is that your actual HTML markup?

Comment: I updated input markup. But result is still the same.

Comment: I think you're just seeing the way strings containing quotes are displayed by your database query application. The backslashes aren't actually in the DB, it just displays strings that way.

Comment: But your HTML markup still looks wrong. It should be either `value="{\"filename\":...}"` or `value='{"filename":...}'`.

Comment: I don't think you can backslash double quotes and use JSON.parse(). I could be wrong but I don't think they're automatically unescaped.

Comment: @Barmar: No, backslashes don't escape html. It would be `value="{&quot; or &#34;:…}"`

Comment: OK, thank you for your edit. The wrong encoding seems to be just a display issue (feature) of your DOM inspector. However, your code looks well, for additional debugging would need to know the exact request sent by the browser (seen in network panel), and the serverside code that receives it and puts it into mongodb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TajsW/)

To make it a valid html

```
<input id="logoVal" type="hidden" value='{"filename":"29f96b40-cca8-11e2-9f83-1561fd356a40.png","cdnUri":"https://abc.s3.amazonaws.com/"}' name="logo">
```

Then you can test using

```
var val = JSON.parse( $("#logoVal").val() );
console.log( val );
alert(val.filename);
```

And you will see that it will convert correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Use single quotes for your value:

```
<input id="logoVal" type="hidden" value='{"filename":"29f96b40-cca8-11e2-9f83-1561fd356a40.png","cdnUri":"https://abc.s3.amazonaws.com/"}' name="logo">
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/uUcnW/

Comment: I actually like that one better than the one I posted.

Comment: @MikeC: But you still mustn't forget to html-encode apostrophes that might occur in the JSON strings then…

Comment: When I write $('#logoVal').val(JSON.stringify(file)) , it puts double-quotes, not single-quotes.